# Why are different conversion functions for int and const int allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, constants, language-lawyer

Why is the following allowed to be compiled in C++?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class mytest
{
public:    
    operator int()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    operator  const int()
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    mytest mt;
    //int x = mt;    //ERROR ambigious 
    //const int x = mt; //ERROR ambigious
}
```

Why does it make sense to allow different versions (based on constness) of the conversion operator to be compiled when their use always results in ambiguity?

Can someone clarify what I am missing here?

Comment: A guess: No one has cared enough to make a list of slightly useful vs totally useless cases, so there is no rule for this in the standard. For example, making it `const int() volatile` might make it useful again. Perhaps.

Comment: There is no rule against useless declarations. Trying to rule out all useless construct is a very bad strategy for language design.

Comment: @curiousguy Compiler throws error for functions differing only in return type..this is just special case of that scenario..so should be errored out

Comment: @code707 By definition functions cannot differ only in return type and the compiler is complaining because of two different declarations of the **same function**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come to the conclusion, that it's not explicitly allowed to write conversation operators that only differ by constness of their return value. It is **too expensive** for the compilation process to explicitly disallow it.

Remember that (member) functions that only differ by their return type

```
class mytest
{
    int f();
    const int f();
};
```

are forbidden:

> error: ‘const int mytest::f()’ cannot be overloaded

It's just that conversion operators start with `operator` that makes the difference.

Comment: The type is part of the conversion function's name, so to speak. It's not really two overloads with only a different return type, it's two different functions.

Comment: @StoryTeller what about adding this as another answer? The answers given so far are not really satisfying ...

Answer (score 18):

For conversion they're ambiguous; but you might call them explicitly. e.g.

```
int x = mt.operator int();
const int x = mt.operator const int();
```

Comment: Do you have an idea in which cases this could make sense?

Comment: In real world, I can't think any.

Comment: Maybe for binding of member function pointers? I don't have the syntax at hand ...

Comment: @Wolf Yes you can do that, but I still don't think it's the appropriate usage of conversion function.

Comment: I think it should be disallowed in standard

Comment: Feel free to write a proposal listing the types which are not permitted to be `const`-qualified here, or justifying why no types (even complex user-defined ones) may be `const`-qualified. Apparently no-one else has felt strongly enough about this to do the work, but you could be the one!

Answer (score 5):

I believe that in the strictest sense, even if it doesn't really make much sense for `const`, this is legitimate.

There is a difference between a function declaration and a function type, and they do not have the same constraints.

Function *declarations* may not differ in only their return type or (since C++17) exception specification. However, no such thing is said about the function *type* (to my knowledge).

The standard [class.conv.fct] decribes conversion functions as having such-and-such form (three alternatives listed), all of which do not look like normal function declarations, in particular they very obviously have no return type.

It *does state*, that the function type is *"function taking no parameter returning conversion-type-id"*, but nowhere is it mentioned that conversion function *declarations* have any such thing as a return type. On the contrary, the three alternative forms listed very clearly do not have a return type.

Since conversion functions don't *have* a return type (... in their declaration), it cannot conflict. So, I guess, in the strictest, most pedantic sense, it's even kinda "legal", whether it makes sense or not.

If you think about it, then it somehow *has to be* legal, too. A class may very well have more than one conversion function to different things (not just differing by `const`). Such code does exist, and it sometimes makes a lot of sense going that way.
You might for example have a class `File` that converts to either a `string` (the filename) or to a `handle_t` (the operating system handle) in case you want to use some OS-specific or exotic function that your wrapper class doesn't directly support (think `writev`, `tee`, or `epoll`?) It's certainly something you'd expect to work!
If, however, we treated conversion functions as "just functions", then they'd only differ in their return type, which would render the declarations illegal. So... that wouldn't work.

Comment: *conversion functions don't have a return type* -- interesting point, that teaches to see conversion operators not like just some kind of function, but like constructors that also have no return type but can be used get objects. And an acceptable answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

> why does it make sense to allow different version(based on constness) of conversion operator (to be compiled) when their use always result in ambiguity;

It usually makes no sense (apart from highly artificial use cases) and a compiler could warn you about it:

```
prog.cc:12:25: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
     operator  const int()
                         ^
```

Comment: Can you add such a use case?

Comment: @Wolf See songyuanyao's answer. The use case is to demonstrate that you can make out a difference by being able to call them separately. That's why I consider highly artificial, it has no real use.

Comment: And because nobody is likely to do that (for obvious reasons), it makes little sense to introduce a wording change that would disallow it. That's my 2 cents, anyway.

Comment: Consider some template code where instead of `int` and `const int` directly you get a more complicated type computation that happens to put out these types for some template arguments.

Comment: @T.C. Maybe, but the example of code707 hasn't introduced any notion of templates.

Comment: Not quite the same, but a slightly different signature:

`operator const int&()`

Makes some sense; if it's a conversion that you know might happen a lot and want to cache it (well, maybe not an int, but a larger object); and if moving it around is expensive for some unknown reason...

Not something I've seen in the real world though.